# What service to use to backup 100+ gigs of data as mounted block-level storage?

Tags: backup, mount, hard-drive

I'm looking for an online solution to mount a drive as block-level storage and perform backups on it.

I'd use S3 for this, but it's not block level.
I'd use rackspace for this, but again, it's not block level.

Dreamhost has a ridiculous amount of space for $10/mo but I'm pretty sure if they found out you are using their space for backups they'll delete your account.

Does anyone have suggestions on what service to use for this? Are there any solutions meant JUST for this?

Mount drive on the cloud as if it were a local external hd, backup/use/etc.

I'm tired of local hard drives failing.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, 
lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-
shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon's AWS Storage Gateway might work for you, it supports iSCSI.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that 100+ GBytes is going to take a LONG time to transfer over any network.  Are you sure that a local disk would not be a better idea?

Have you considered using one of those local USB disks?

Does this have to be a user oriented, managed resource or not?

If you are looking for a backup service that does this in the background, I can name about three or four that generally have good reputations but it uses a client/external server to do its work and you will not have direct access to the backup like a mountpoint.  But you will have access to backed up information on-line using either the client or a supplied website.

You have not stated which operating system, I'm assumming Linux.